# Cannot declare controller in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am developing a web application. In my application, I am using Angular JS. I am new to Angular JS. But now I am having a problem my declaring controller. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
 //files references
</head>
<script>
var app = angular.module('memeApp',['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);
</script>
<nav class="nav-bar">
<a href="page1">Home</a>
<a href="page2">Account</a>
</nav>
<div class="content" ng-app="memeApp" ng-controller="DefaultController">
//content
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I did nothing yet. I declare a controller named DefaultController. So when I check log, it is giving me following error:

[image]

So my controller is totally not working. When I add js code for controller as well. If I removed controller directive, errors gone. Why is my controller not working?

Comment: I don't see your controller defined anywhere, only you calling it when it doesn't exist

Comment: You declared a controller that you didn't define. Remove it from your DOM or declare it as following : `app.controller('DefaultController', function(){});`

Comment: As you can see I added ng-controller="DefaultController" besides ng-app declaration. @SterlingArcher

Comment: There's a major difference between adding the controller, and defining it. ng-controller expects the controller to exist, and you haven't defined one.

Comment: Here is a couple of mini-advices: 1.You are missing the open '<body> tag 2. You should put the script bloque just before of closing the '</body>' tag. 3. Read the answer from @Mickers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a controller function 'DefaultController' before you use it in html div tag.

Add below code in your script tag.

```
app.controller('DefaultController', ['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your controller somewhere and add it as a dependency to the app first.
Example:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
    .controller('DefaultController' function() {
        //do stuff
    };
```

and in your app definition:

```
var app = angular.module('memeApp',['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap', 'app.controllers']);
```